# Not able to click in any content in box coming after using "Show a popup when hovering over a link or button"

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am not able to click in content of popup which comes after using "Show a popup when hovering over a link or button".

i am link to code that i am using: http://jsfiddle.net/8UkHn/

please help me either by suggesting an edit in same code or a new code.

thanks.

```js
$("a").hover(function(e) {
    $($(this).data("tooltip")).css({
        left: e.pageX + 1,
        top: e.pageY + 1
    }).stop().show(100);
}, function() {
    $($(this).data("tooltip")).hide();
});
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://foo.com" data-tooltip="#foo">foo</a>
<br><br>
<a href="http://bar.com" data-tooltip="#bar">bar</a>

<div id="foo">
    
    foo means foo
    <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
</div>
<div id="bar">bar means bar</div>
```

Comment: You want to click the `<a>` in `#foo` that has words 'Anyhing can go here!', right?

Comment: yes . basically i want to be able to click on any part inside popup , be it link or text . link can be clicked and text can be copied.

Comment: By the way why do you want to click on `tool tip`? `Tool tip` are not for this purpose

Comment: ok. then what can i use to serve my purpose? please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

When your mouse moves out of the `<a>` tag, the tooltip associated with it is immediately hidden. Because of this, you won't be able to click on anything inside the tooltip.

The solution is to keep the tooltip open as long as the mouse is inside your `<a>` or its associated tooltip.

Check demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8UkHn/2108/

Code:

```
$("a").hover(function(e) {
    $($(this).data("tooltip")).css({
        left: e.pageX + 1,
        top: e.pageY + 1
    }).stop().show(100);

    // clear any timer started for hiding the tooltip
    if($(this).data("hidetimer")) {
        clearTimeout($(this).data("hidetimer"));
        $(this).data("hidetimer", 0);
    }

}, function() {

    // start a timer for hiding the tooltip
    // after 500ms so as to give the user time to move his 
    // mouse over to the tooltip
    var tooltip = $($(this).data("tooltip"));
    $(this).data("hidetimer", setTimeout(function() {
        tooltip.hide();
    }, 500));

});

$('[data-tooltip]').each(function() {
    var self = $(this), tooltip = $(self.data("tooltip"));

    // similar show/hide logic for when the mouse enters/leaves the tooltip
    tooltip.hover(function() {
        if(self.data("hidetimer")) {
            clearTimeout(self.data("hidetimer"));
            self.data("hidetimer", 0);
        }
    }, function() {
        self.data("hidetimer", setTimeout(function() {
            tooltip.hide();
        }, 500));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As your tooltips are outside of your `a` tag that you hover, when you try to hover the tooltip, it disapear, you should keep your tooltip inside your hover target to avoid this behaviour.

Please,try this:

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8UkHn/2112/))

```js
$(".container").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".tooltip").css({
        left: e.pageX + 1,
        top: e.pageY + 1
    }).stop().show(100);
}, function() {
    $(this).children(".tooltip").hide();
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.container{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<span class="container" data-tooltip="#foo">
    <a href="http://foo.com" >foo</a>
    <div id="foo" class="tooltip" >foo means foo</div>
</span>
<span class="container" data-tooltip="#bar">
    <a href="http://bar.com" >bar</a>
    <div id="bar" class="tooltip" >bar means bar</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you explain it too??

Comment: yes this is also fine but it keeps tooltip insilde hover target, i think previous is better because it does not hide the hover target and keeps tooltip in space associated with <a>

Comment: @JuniusRendel - If we can have a common container, then we do not even need any JS to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/vn1bpeag/

Comment: yes, that's obvious, however, I started from his codebase, and CSS is not the only answer, if it has dynamic content loaded on hover, for example.